# Problem with redirection to HttpWebResponse Uri with basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest

I need to redirect user outside my web application to the page that uses basic authentication.

Here's what I have been trying for quite a bit:

```cs
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;    

String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
return this.Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
```

I have also tried cache scenario, but with no success:

```cs
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

            myCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
            req.Credentials = myCache;
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: Standard basic auth requires just `req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);`. But it depends on the service you're connecting to. You can also add `req.PreAuthenticate = true;`, it works better in some situations. If you have to use the header, add it with `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` and encode the credential using `UTF8` or `ASCII`. `ISO-8859-1` may not get it right, it depends on the actual charset in use.

Answer (score 1):

> redirect user outside my web application to the page that uses basic authentication

So you want to *redirect* someone to a different page, and that page requires basic authentication? So you want to send the user to that target page?

Then you won’t be able to just request that target page with basic authentication and doing something with it. You basically have two options here:

1. Retrieve the *content* from that other page and present it yourself. This will not redirect the user but keep them on your site.
2. Redirect to the URL of the target page but include the credentials as part of the URL so that the user’s browser will use these credentials to perform basic authentication agains that page.

   URLs with basic authentication credentials usually look like this: `https://username:password@example.com/`.

   So you will actually have to expose the credentials to the user if you want them to redirect there. Otherwise you will not be able to have them go there on their own, as there is no way to pass authentication without making that visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Will be there a possibility to redirect if the page would require other type of authentication (e.g. forms authentication)?

Comment: Only if the target page allows you to pass the credentials in some other way. But in any case, you should note that this exposes the credentials to the end user. So this might be undesirable.